# Which segments have at least one end inside polygon?

Tags: algorithm, geometry

I have a problem I'm considering:

[It will look something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVBzT.png)

We have a collection of segments and a polygon. What will be the algorithm that finds segments that have at least one of their ends inside the polygon?

Edit: We can assume that the polygon is always convex.

Edit2: I was thinking to approach this problem with segment intersections but I really don't know how.

Edit3: Now i thought maybe to try it with Point In Polygon algorithm, am I right? I can forget about segments for a moment, because all that I'm interested in are the ends of segments which are points, right? So maybe I can somehow check all of the points if they're within polygon. For these that are in we have the answer.

Comment: Is the polygon always convex?

Comment: We can assume that for simplicity.

Comment: `Point In Polygon` is not good when you have the only polygon and a lot of points to check. You need some pre-treatment to use spatial data like one in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make dissection of polygon into trapezoids with two horizontal edges (using horizontal lines through polygon vertices)

Filte out points that lie outside polygon bounding box

For every endpoint find whether lies in some trapezoid with binary search by Y-coordinate and some math for left/right trapezoid edges.

Let we have found appropriate trapezoid, we know trapezoid top and bottom Y (and `bottom<=py<=top`), and left and right edges equations. If left top point is `(xlt, top)`, left bottom point is `(xlb, bottom)` then left edge equation is

```
x * (top - bottom) + y * (xlb - xlt) + (xlt * bottom - xlb * top) = 0
```

and similar for the right edge with `xrt, xrb`.

When we substitute endpoint coordinates `px, px` into this expression, we will get some value. Sign of this value tells us where point is relative to line (which side).

If **signs** for left and right lines **differs**, **point is** between edges, i.e. **inside** trapezoid.

Comment: Yea, nice idea, but as you said "some math". For me the "math" is the problem.

Comment: I added some description